# Typescript code within jQuery callback function

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to put the typescript code inside the jQuery callback function. This is an Angular 6 component ts file. I'm using Material DataTable as HTML template. When I click a button, I want to first let the row fadeout, then update the mongoDB, and then repaginate my datatable.

Right now in this sequence, the fadeOut does not work properly because the update function is not inside the callback function of jQuery (I guess).

Could someone please shed some light?

Thx

```js
onSetOK(user: USER, i: number) {
  const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(user);
  console.log(index);

  //here begins the jQuery code to let the row fadeout
  $().ready(function() {
    const $row = $('#row' + i);
    $row.fadeOut(1000, function(e) {

      $row.remove();
      // put the below typescript code here
    });
  });

  //typescript code, update mongoDB
  this.service.updateUserOK(user).subscribe(res => {

    this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  });

}
```

```html
...

<ng-container matColumnDef='Actions'>
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Actions </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef='let u, let i = index' (click)='$event.stopPropagation()'>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)='onSetOK(u, i)'>
      <i class='fas fa-check fa-2x'></i>
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-row *matRowDef='let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns(); let i = index;' attr.id='row{{i}}'></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missusing the ready function. Quote from the *jQuery API Docs*:

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Because your DOM is at this point fully loaded, the callback will never be called. Just execute your fade effect like this:

```
onSetOK(user: USER, i: number) {
  const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(user);
  console.log(index);

  //here begins the jQuery code to let the row fadeout
  const $row = $('#row' + i);
  $row.fadeOut(1000, (e) => {

    $row.remove();
    // put the below typescript code here

    //typescript code, update mongoDB
    this.service.updateUserOK(user).subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  });
}
```